# Turn off omitting of repeated authors

Tags: biblatex

Is there an elegant way to globally disable the omission of repeated authors in `biblatex`? I know I can call `\citereset` manually with that effect, so I could redefine `\cite` and friends to include a `\citereset`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{author2014,
author = {Author, My},
title = {Book 2014},
year = {2014}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Some text.{\footnote{\cite[1]{author2014}} 
Some more text.{\footnote{\cite[2]{author2014}}
Even more text.\citereset{\footnote{\cite[3]{author2014}}

\let\oldcite\cite
\def\cite{\citereset\oldcite}

Again some text.\footnote{\cite[4]{author2014}}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Footnotes with cite commands]

Is this the way to go or am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't you just use `\footcite[1]{author2014}`, `\footcite[2]{author2014}`? Omitting the author within the same paragraph seems to be Chicago standard. In footnotes, however, such a thing does not make sense.

Comment: @moewe Yes, I did try it, but it also omitted the repeating authors.

Comment: Ahh, I see that now. The problem is that you are using a style with footnotes that (from what I can tell) is not really intended for use in footnotes: CMS `authordate` style is used inline, while `note` normally goes in the footnotes. I find it quite odd to only add a author-year citation in a footnote. If you, however, need a `\cite` for a longer text in a footnote I would suggest manually adding a `\citereset`, because you don't want to disable the tracking in the document body, if you want to be CMS-compliant.

Comment: My advice is still to use the `note` style for footnote citations, but one can solve this issue with a few lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

We can make sure that only in footnotes we reset the ibid-tracker with

```
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{\global\undef\blx@lastkey@foot}
\makeatother
```

Then we disable the ibid-tracker in footnotes only so that we still get meaningful footnotes while not losing CMS compliance for the text body. (Though I think totally strict CMS would require to issue a `\citerest` after each paragraph, see p. 114 of the [`biblatex-chicago` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf): "Technically, [the ibid mechanism] should only [apply] when a source is cited 'more than once in one paragraph' (15.26), so you can use the `\citereset` command from `biblatex` to achieve the greatest compliance, as the package only offers automatic resetting on part, chapter, section, and subsection boundaries, while `biblatex-chicago` automatically resets the tracker at page breaks.")

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{\global\undef\blx@lastkey@foot}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text.\footcite[1]{sigfridsson}
Some more text.\footnote{\cite[2]{sigfridsson}}
Even more text.\footcite[3]{sigfridsson}
Again some text.\footcite[4]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want real "ibid" in the footnotes at least, go with

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@noibid}%
  {\blx@ibidreset%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}%
  {\iffootnote
     {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
        \bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}
     {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{prenote}\AND%
                  \iffieldundef{postnote}}%
        {\blx@ibidreset%
         \usebibmacro{cite}%
         \PackageWarning{biblatex-chicago}%
           {Empty Ibidem citation}}%
        {\toggletrue{cms@inlineibid}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text.\footcite[1]{sigfridsson}
Some more text.\footnote{\Cite[2]{sigfridsson}}
Even more text.\footcite[3]{sigfridsson}
Again some text.\footcite[4]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]